# Are there any real advantages to upgrading to PEAR::MDB2 from PEAR::DB?

Tags: php, pear, mdb2

We have a very large legacy codebase and I was wondering if there's any REAL advantage to upgrading to MDB2.

Thoughts? Speed? Readability? Fewer bugs? Anything at all?

Thanks

Comment: DB doesn't properly support 'bit' fields, which caused me no end of grief until I figured that out and worked around it. Use MDB2 if you can, or even PDO for a more widely support option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DB is not maintained anymore. MDB2 gets updates, is more stable and feature-complete.

Comment: Just a hint: in 2011 I am sure this was the correct answer. Today (2015) everyone should compare the release dates:
    PEAR DB 1.8.2 (stable) was released on 2014-11-27
    PEAR MDB2 2.5.0b5 (beta) was released on 2012-10-29